# Dart HTML Server. How do I have the server refuse more than one client connection?

Tags: webserver, dart

I'm writing a web application that is to be used by only one client and want to accept only one connection to the server. The LAN will be confined to an aircraft.  I'm really new to Dart, HTML etc. How can I refuse multiple connections to the server?

Here's my code fir the HTTP server -

```dart
class MicroServer {

  var address;
  var port;

  var httpServer;    // global

  MicroServer(this.address, this.port) {
    final HTTP_ROOT_PATH = Platform.script.resolve('../build/web').toFilePath();
    final virDir = new VirtualDirectory(HTTP_ROOT_PATH)
      ..jailRoot = false  
      ..allowDirectoryListing = true;

  HttpServer.bind(address, port)
    .then((httpserver) {
    httpServer = httpserver;
    httpserver.listen((request) {
        virDir.serveRequest(request);
      });
    });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that the code below works so far.  I could also have taken advantage of

```dart
 if(request.session.isNew) // then grab the session.id etc.
```

but it's just as easy to use the session.id variable since I will use it anyway.

```dart
class MicroServer {

  var address;
  var port;

  var httpServer; 
  var sessionID;  // null until first request received


  MicroServer(this.address, this.port) {
    final HTTP_ROOT_PATH = Platform.script.resolve('../build/web').toFilePath();
    final virDir = new VirtualDirectory(HTTP_ROOT_PATH)
      ..jailRoot = false  // process links will work
      ..followLinks = true
      ..allowDirectoryListing = true;

  HttpServer.bind(address, port)
    .then((httpserver) {
      httpServer = httpserver;
      httpserver.idleTimeout = null;
      print("micro server started on ${httpserver.address}:${httpserver.port}");
      httpserver.listen((request) {
        if(sessionID == null) {
          sessionID = request.session.id;
          virDir.serveRequest(request);
        } else if(sessionID == request.session.id){
          virDir.serveRequest(request);
        } else {
          request.response.writeln('ERROR - Connection is in use.');
          request.response.close();
          request.session.destroy();
        }
      });
    }).catchError((e) => print(e.toString()));
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Dart is single-threaded, so you can safely use check a variable to see if there's a current connection:

```dart
  bool hasClient = false;

  HttpServer.bind(address, port)
    .then((httpserver) {
    httpServer = httpserver;
    httpserver.listen((request) {
        if (hasClient) {
          sendBusyPage(request);
        } else {
          hasClient = true;
          virDir.serveRequest(request);
          hasClient = false;
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: It looks like the normal `serveRequest` case should be in an `else` clause.

Comment: Thanks Justin! I presume that in sendbusyPage() there will be a line request.response = . I need to provide the object.  I now have a file "too_many_clients.html" in my Dart Editor web folder.  What is the object? the relative path to the html file? or ?. After the client connects all communication between the client and server side Dart code will be by web socket.

Comment: I added two print statements to your code; the first is executed the second is not.  I infer from that that registered listener listens to HTML requests after the page or pages are served.  I need to prevent the server from accepting a second connection.